# 'TemplateDoesNotExist at /' error during local development

Tags: python, django

I am following two scoops of django and mozilla tutorial for deploying my app. 
I set up a virtual env and base setting, local setting,etc and when i ran the command :

`./manage.py runserver 0:8000 --settings=Books.settings.local`

the browser showed the error, template home not found...
I think there might be some problem due to the env, i am not sure.

**base.py**

```
import os


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '2z9y'
# Simplified static file serving.
# https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost','https://hackingonlineeducation.herokuapp.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #third party apps
    'star_ratings',
    'crispy_forms',
    #my_apps
    'newsletter',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Books.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Books.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static","bootstrap")
    # '/var/www/static/',
]
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static','static_root')

MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media','profile_images')

#crispy_forms
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='profile'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL='home'
```

**local.py**

```
from Books.settings.base import *

DEBUG = True
INSTALLED_APPS += (
    'debug_toolbar', # and other apps for local development
)

MIDDLEWARE +=[
'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware'
]
```

the error in the browser :

```
Exception Location:     /home/user/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in get_template, line 25
Python Executable:  /home/user/usr/bin/python
Python Version:     3.6.1
Python Path:    

['/home/user/workspace/Books',
 '/home/user/usr/lib/python36.zip',
 '/home/user/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/home/user/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/home/user/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/home/user/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Sphinx-1.5.6-py3.6.egg',
 '/home/user/workspace/speakerfight/src/django-queryset-csv',
 '/home/user/workspace/speakerfight/src/django-activelink']

Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /home/user/workspace/Books/Books/templates/home.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/user/workspace/Books/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/home.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/user/workspace/Books/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/home.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/user/workspace/Books/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/star_ratings/templates/home.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/user/workspace/Books/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/crispy_forms/templates/home.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/user/workspace/Books/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/debug_toolbar/templates/home.html (Source does not exist)
```

Also i have update manage.py as follows :

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Books.settings.local")
```

Comment: On the error page which says the template wasn't found, there should be (further down) a list of directories that were searched to find the template. This should be under the section titled "Template-loader postmortem", [see here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/#template-postmortem). Can you please post what that says?

Comment: your error traceback clearly stats `/home/user/workspace/Books/Books/templates/home.html` doublecheck if the file exists and its permission

Comment: @ubadub and @Gahan thanks for answering! i just noticed that the template loader is loading templates from `/home/user/workspace/Books/Books/templates/home.html` where it should be `/home/user/workspace/Books/templates/home.html`, i am confused ,the BASE_DIR seems to be ok?

Comment: Templates *should* be in `/Books/Books/templates/`. Why did you expect otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

> BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

Specifies the BASE_DIR as the *parent* directory of the current directory in which your base.py lives. This means BASE_DIR will refer to `/home/user/workspace/Books/Books/`

You should try this:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(PROJECT_ROOT)
```

and then in `TEMPLATES:`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'templates')],
        ...
]
```

Comment: thanks. i removed different setting files and just added this : `DEBUG = bool( os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG', True) )`. it's working now.